# create a table if not exits in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I want to create a table in postgresql which is not exists.

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">toor</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hbm2dll.auto">update</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping class="org.firsthibernatproject.dto.Person"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Enity :**

```
@Entity
@Table (name="PERSON_DETAILS")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column (name="id")
    private int id;
    @Column (name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column (name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    private Date joinedDate;
    private String adresse;
    private String description;



    public String getAdresse() {
        return adresse;
    }
    public void setAdresse(String adresse) {
        this.adresse = adresse;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Date getJoinedDate() {
        return joinedDate;
    }
    public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) {
        this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }


}
```

And this is the code I tried to create the new table :

```
public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setId(3);
        person.setFirstName("Orihime");
        person.setLastName("Inoue");
        person.setAdresse("Karakura Town");
        person.setJoinedDate(new Date());
        person.setDescription("She has a unique power.");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(person);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

As you can see in the `hbm2dll.auto` property I used the value `update` which will create the table if not exists in the database, but instead I get this error message in the eclipse's console :

```
Hibernate: insert into PERSON_DETAILS (adresse, description, first_name, joinedDate, last_name, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
mai 24, 2014 2:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
mai 24, 2014 2:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERREUR: la relation « person_details » n'existe pas
  Position : 13
mai 24, 2014 2:49:06 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

which says that the table I try to add doesn't exist.

How can I allow my program to create the new table.

I also had another problem, which is adding a new column to a table which is already created, it shows me that the column is not exits, but that column should be created if not exists in the table.

Comment: Would you try changing the property name to hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto

Comment: That was the problem, thanks :)
Could you post this comment as an answer so that I can make this topic as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the property name to

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
```